# How to safely download files from Telegram using Sandboxie?

Tags: sandbox, telegram

I need to download certain files from Telegram. It is mostly images and videos. I am aware that even this kind of files can contain malicious code, so I want to be 100% safe. (The files usually surpass 20 MB, so it is not scannable through DrWebBot on Telegram.)

**Is the following way of downloading files safe?**

1. Open Telegram in Sandboxie.
2. Download the wanted file into my PC. Since it’s running in Sandboxie, the downloaded file will also be only visible in Sandboxie.
3. Therefore, I open my downloads folder (Windows Explorer) in Sandboxie.
4. I open a web browser, also in Sandboxie, and upload the downloaded file to VirusTotal.com to scan for malware.
5. If the report says no threat found, I can now close Sandboxie and safely download the file from Telegram (and maybe upload it again on VirusTotal.com).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is extremely rare for video or image files to contain code-execution exploits that will work even if the file isn't viewed. Indeed, it is approximately impossible for any file to exploit anything if the file isn't opened at all, but unfortunately Windows Explorer (and the Windows common dialogs including the Save File dialog) will open the files to read basic data and/or generate thumbnails, so there is still a little risk. The safest way to do this would be to use a command-line interface that doesn't interact with the contents of the files at all.

Furthermore, you shouldn't fully count on Virustotal. They're very good at recognizing known malware and many common malware patterns, but malware authors are fully aware of this and don't generally release malware until it's obfuscated enough that virustotal doesn't recognize it (which they can themselves test, of course). Eventually Virustotal's detection will be updated to detect that malware too - it's a constant arms race - but it's not safe to assume that a file is clean just because VT doesn't detect anything.

A simple additional test - if you trust your sandboxing enough - would be open the files and view them through, within a sandbox. This also doesn't guarantee anything - it's not impossible to make a media file that contains a code execution exploit and also renders correctly - but it does raise the bar. Ideally, use a decoder (codec) and player that aren't the common ones the intended audience of the hypothetical malware would use. If you can do it in a different OS and ideally different platform altogether - for example, on an ARM-based Linux system, if you expect it's targeting x86 Windows - that will both reduce your risk and increase the chance that anything fishy with the file crashes the player or corrupts the output, rather than silently succeeding.

If you want to be extra thorough, use Sysinternals Process Monitor or similar to monitor system calls that the process makes (either a media player or Explorer or whatever) when opening the suspicious files, vs. when opening a trusted file of the same kind. If the process doesn't even attempt any unexpected system calls, that's a reasonably clear indication that the media file isn't attempting code execution.

With all that said, though, this is broadly a reasonable approach. You might consider using a VM (without host integration features) in addition to sandboxie / a non-Windows OS / other OS-based sandboxing (e.g. Windows' AppContainers, something like Firejail on Linux, etc.), just for defense in depth + snapshot potential, but that's also additional work that is probably only called for if the media files are extremely suspect.